# Está aparecendo erro syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Tags: syntax-error, token-ajax

Estou usando onOptionsItemSelected e está dando esse erro

Código

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.example.myapplication.CriarPersonagemActivity;
import com.example.myapplication.CriarPersonagemHelper;
import com.example.myapplication.dao.personagensDAO;
import com.example.myapplication.modelo.Personagem;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
public class CriarPersonagemActivity extends Activity { 

private  CriarPersonagemHelper Helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.criarpersonagem);
        
    Helper=new CriarPersonagemHelper(this);
}
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
         
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_criarpersonagem,  menu);      
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) { 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_criarpersonagem_salvar:
         
             Personagem personagem =    Helper.pegaPersonagem();
             personagensDAO dao = new personagensDAO(this);
             dao.insere(personagem);
             dao.close();
             Toast.makeText(CriarPersonagemActivity.this, "Personagem salvo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
        
Button voltar = (Button) findViewById (R.id.criar_personagem_voltar);
voltar.setOnClickListener(new  View. OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick (View v)  {
          finish();
         }
   }) ;
         
}
 }
```

Comment: bem vindo ao stack overflow. Dica: Quando for colocar algum código aqui, tenta colocar ele mais identado pois estava muito dificil entender onde estava o problema

Comment: se a resposta foi util e resolveu seu problema, por favor marque como resolvida

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Respondendo sobre sua pergunta, identando o código é fácil perceber que no metódo `onCreateOptionsMenu` falta uma chave final para fechado e tem uma chave sobrando no final do algoritmo...  seu código final ficaria assim:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.example.myapplication.CriarPersonagemActivity;
import com.example.myapplication.CriarPersonagemHelper;
import com.example.myapplication.dao.personagensDAO;
import com.example.myapplication.modelo.Personagem;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
public class CriarPersonagemActivity extends Activity { 

    private  CriarPersonagemHelper Helper;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.criarpersonagem);
            
        Helper=new CriarPersonagemHelper(this);
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
             
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_criarpersonagem,  menu);      
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_criarpersonagem_salvar:
             
                 Personagem personagem =    Helper.pegaPersonagem();
                 personagensDAO dao = new personagensDAO(this);
                 dao.insere(personagem);
                 dao.close();
                 Toast.makeText(CriarPersonagemActivity.this, "Personagem salvo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                 finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
            
    Button voltar = (Button) findViewById (R.id.criar_personagem_voltar);
    voltar.setOnClickListener(new  View. OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick (View v)  {
              finish();
          }
    }) ;
         
   }
```

Comment: Obgd ajudou, agr o erro é na xml do projeto kk quando eu abro a Activity onde eu coloquei a actionBar ele fecha o app

Comment: olha qual erro ta dando no codigo java

Comment: Eu revisei o projeto e era um erro de digitação meu

Comment: boa, resolvido entaone

Comment: Sim obgd pela atenção